# PPLB - Printing Qr Code

Tags: printing

I'm printing a barcode in an Argox Printer using **PPLB** to send the command. But now i need to print a Qr Code in the label.

I tried to see examples in the manual, but there is nothing about Qr code.

Answer (score 0):

QR Codes did not exist at the time of PPLB,
The only addition really to the specification is the GWT graphics print command -

PPLB is the incorrect format to print QR Codes with. You may find a font template or build one I guess - but inherently it is not designed for it :)

Look at PPLZ or similar (something not built and designed for and in the era of DOS) - [https://www.michaelkrug.de/Update/pplz_e.pdf#:~:text=The%20PPLZ%20command%20set%20is%20a%20software%20interface,the%20exact%20patterns%20for%20the%20host%20and%20user](https://www.michaelkrug.de/Update/pplz_e.pdf#:%7E:text=The%20PPLZ%20command%20set%20is%20a%20software%20interface,the%20exact%20patterns%20for%20the%20host%20and%20user).

Page 31